# How to pass params object[i] to a template function in C#

Tags: c#, templates, parameters

I am trying to send a params object[i] to a T function but I cant find the right syntax.

Here is an example to show the context of what I am trying to achieve:

```
private bool decodeValue<T>(int id,ref T item, string code)
{

    if(!TypeDescriptor.GetConverter (item).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
    {
        errorThrow (id + 2);
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        item = ((T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter (item).ConvertFromString (code));
    }
    catch 
    {
        errorThrow (id + 2);
        //item = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool decodeValues(string[] code, int id, params object[] items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) 
    {
        System.Type t = items [i].GetType(); 
        //in this part i cant find the correct syntax
        if(decodeValue<(t)items[i]>(id, ref items[i] as t, code[i+2]))
        {

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

At the line `decodeValue<(t)items[i]>(id, ref items[i] as t, code[i+2]`
no matter what syntax I try, the compiler tells me that after `>` it expects a `)`

I could inline the function decodeValue into the for loop but I think there is a more elegant way of doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: also does not work
             if(decodeValue<typeof(t)>(id, ref items[i], code[i+2]))

Comment: Why do you need `T` in the first place? Your code looks like you could just use `ref object item`

Comment: because i first made decodeValue and after i said to myself it would be nicer to do it in batch so i added decodeValues and tried to adapt it to decodeValue. decodeValue at first was a good use of template since i was sending every value of a message one by one hard coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you replace content of items. Why do even need templated function? Just do this:

```
private bool decodeValue(int id,ref object item, string code)
{

    if(!TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(item).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
    {
        errorThrow (id + 2);
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        item = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(item).ConvertFromString(code);
    }
    catch 
    {
        errorThrow (id + 2);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool decodeValues(string[] code, int id, params object[] items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) 
    {
        //in this part i cant find the correct syntax
        if(decodeValue(id, ref items[i], code[i+2]))
        {

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you ever need type of item in your code, just call .GetType() where it actualy needed. That is not only good way to do things, but in some cases performance effective (compiler can greatly optimise some calls of this function).

Comment: thanks
this is what happen when you add stuff on something without thinking of changing the base design.

Instead of adapting decodeList for decodeValue i should have done the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

generics (`<T>`) and reflection (`.GetType()`) are not good friends. There is no *convenient* way to express that. You *can*, however, abuse `dynamic` to do it, *but* you can't easily use `ref` in that case. Further, you can't `ref` between an `object` and a `T`. So basically, there's a lot of hurdles. Frankly, I think you should assess whether `decodeValue<T>` really needs to be generic. In this scenario - especially when using `TypeDescriptor` - I very much doubt that it needs to be. I suspect your best bet would  be to have:

```
private bool DecodeValue(int id, ref object item, Type type, string code)
```

Comment: the function decode in batch a server communication in a form of string

Comment: @CedricRaymond I'm not sure what that would change, if anything... that doesn't make generics a good or bad fit...

Comment: each function have a different set of parameter that has to be decoded and checked for error
the type can be int, byte, long, string, bool, DateTime

Comment: @CedricRaymond again... that doesn't change anything. Without seeing where you are using `T` in `decodeValue<T>`, I strongly suspect that it isn't needed. In particular, you're using `TypeConverter`, and `TypeConverter`  works with `Type`, not `<T>`

Answer (score 0):

The generics' syntax if for compile time while GetType() is for runtime. You cannot mix them of use them together.

A generic class is resolved while you source is converted to binary. The type or interface provided in a generic type is used in that area.

On the contrary GetType returns a type during execution. That type cannot be inserted in a generic definition because compilation has already be done at that time.

Comment: Actually this isn't  quite true; IL is much more flexible than you might  think, and everything you mention *can* be done with  types not known until runtime. It just  isn't  *convenient*. For example, you can use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` - or much more conveniently, there are ways to use  `dynamic` to get the runtime  to make the switch. But  it is *inelegant*, and usually means you shouldn't be doing that in the first place. The  key point is that with C# (in contrast to Java or C++), the generic type information is **retained** during compilation; it is not erased by the compiler

Comment: because of the webgl target i cant use reflection
This is really annoying, otherwise i would never had this problem